# Bandstructure Plots in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, visualization, physics, data-visualization

I am trying to make a gnuplot script that would produce a clone of the following output -
[image: Phonon Dispersion Relations in Insulators - by Bilz,Kress - Springer Berlin]

The features I would like to incorporate are -
 1. Multiplots to show transitions from one symmetry point to another - no questions
 2. Latex/MathJax Labels in wxt terminal - possible?
 3. Ability to switch between the two notations for symmetry points - e.g [00ζ] and Z
 4. Labellings of the branches must be done by hand- inserting coordinates in the script manually.

If there are other features that seem apparent to you please comment.
For the answer to be marked correct - please answer on the best way to proceed on features 2 &3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 2: No, it is not possible to use LaTeX or MathJax for the labels in the wxt terminal. But thats only for the interactive part.

In this case, you can use `utf8` and `enhanced` to get at least the correct symbols:

```
set encoding utf8
set termoption enhanced

set xlabel '[00ζ]'
set label at graph 0.5,0.5 'Σ_1(0)'
plot x
```

For a print-quality image, you can use `set terminal cairolatex pdf` to use LaTeX for the labels:

```
set terminal cairolatex pdf standalone
set output 'test.tex'
set bmargin 3
set xlabel '$[00\zeta]$'
set label at graph 0.5,0.5 '$\Sigma_1(0)$'
plot x
set output
system('pdflatex test.tex')
```

Here, you must pay attention to use single quotes `'`, otherwise you must escape some characters.

Regarding 3: There is no 'automatic' way to switch between the two variants, but you can of course define all labels as string, and choose between the two:

```
latex = 1
if (latex) {
    xlabel = '$[00\zeta]$'
    label1 = '$\Sigma_1(0)$'
} else {
    xlabel = '[00ζ]'
    label1 = 'Σ_1(0)'
}
set xlabel xlabel
set label 1 at graph 0.5,0.5 label1
```

In general that works, but since gnuplot doesn't know about the exact width and height of a LaTeX label, some fine-tuning of the label position might be required (e.g. with `offset` for the `xlabel`, or with different positions. In that case you can define the whole commands and call them later:

```
latex = 1
if (latex) {
    set_xlabel = 'set xlabel ''$[00\zeta]$'' offset 0,-1'
    set_label1 = 'set label 1 ''$\Sigma_1(0)$'' at graph 0.5,0.5'
} else {
    set_xlabel = 'set xlabel ''[00ζ]'' '
    set_label1 = 'set label 1 ''Σ_1(0)'' at graph 0.5,0.5'
}
set macros
@set_xlabel
@set_label1
```

Instead of using `macros`, you could also use `eval(set_xlabel)`, which would allow you to define a function like:

```
set_label1(x,y) = sprintf('set label 1 ''$\Sigma_1(0)$'' at graph %f,%f', x, y)
eval(set_label1(0.5,0.5))
```

Comment: wow .. hadn't thought of using unicode characters. i looked it up that `{/Symbol a}` should work for Greek Characters (alpha is in this example).  
but that did not work in wxt! Shouldn't the `{/Symbol}` construct work?

Comment: Yes, but that works only in enhanced mode: `set termoption enhanced; set xlabel '{/Symbol a}'; plot x`.